# make directory in ubuntu16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, mkdir

I'm trying to create a directory in PHP using function mkdir() but it throws a warning mkdir(): Permission denied.

I tried with below code

```
     function makeDir()
     {
         $foldername = "/home/administrator/Downloads/pdfs/";
         $oldmask = umask(0);
         mkdir($foldername, 0777);
         umask($oldmask);
     }
```

How can I make new directory with permission?? thanks.

Comment: You need write privileges in the target directory

Comment: @SrThompson how to give privileges in the target directory??

Comment: `chmod -R 777 /home/administrator/Downloads`

Answer (score 0):

Which user does your web server run as? You can see that if you write.

```
ps aux
```

and take a look. It is probably the user www-data (if you use Ubuntu).

Then you chown the dir to that user and give the user write permissions to the directory.

```
chown www-data /var/www/
```

and

```
chmod u+w /var/www/
```

An alternative is to instead use group permissions.

```
chgrp www-data /var/www/
```

and

```
chmod g+w /var/www/
```

assuming the web server runs as group www-data.

Or

You can follow these steps:

**Numeric permissions can solve your problem.**

```
sudo chmod 775 'your directory'
```

if you want to know why only 775 here's your answer

```
400 read by owner
040 read by group
004 read by anybody
200 write by owner
020 write by group
002 write by anybody
100 execute by owner
010 execute by group
001 execute by anybody

 400
+040
+004
+200
+020
+100
+010
+001
=775
```

It will give all permission except write by anybody.